# Seo using a container with class hidden with links inside as fallback of a carousel SSR

Tags: seo, google

I'm using svelteKit and swiper to make a carousel. It works fine, and it is pretty cool, but the problem is there is no HTML output as SSR. Inside the carousel, I've got a bunch of linked articles. To show google these links, I thought of

`<div class="hidden">` list of links

Can I be penalized by google?

Comment: Related: [Would Google think a hidden "skip to content" link is deceptive?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/79118/would-google-think-a-hidden-skip-to-content-link-is-deceptive)

Comment: Also related: [How bad is it to use display: none in CSS?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-bad-is-it-to-use-display-none-in-css)

Comment: You should also read this post from the usability stack and reconsider using a carousel: [Are carousels effective?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/are-carousels-effective)